# Strengthened version of Isoperimetric inequality with n-polygon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, conjectures

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with the lengths $a, b, c, d$ and the area $S$. The main result in [our paper](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/81-86.pdf) equivalent to:

\begin{equation} a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \ge 4S + \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum{(a-b)^2}\end{equation}

where $\sum{(a-b)^2}=(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2+(b-d)^2+(c-d)^2$ and note that $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is the best constant for this inequality.

Similarly with the same form above apply to n-polygon, I propose a conjecture that:

> Let a convex polygon $A_1A_2...A_n$ with the lengths are $a_1, a_2, ...a_n$ and area $S$ we have:
>
> \begin{equation} \sum_i^n{a_i^2} \ge 4\tan{\frac{\pi}{n}}S + k\sum_{i < j}{(a_i-a_j)^2}\end{equation}
>
> I guess that $k=tan{\frac{\pi}{n}}-tan{\frac{\pi}{n+2}}$
>
> I am looking for a proof of the inequality above.

Note that using [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) we can prove that:

\begin{equation} \sum_i^n{a_i^2} \ge 4\tan{\frac{\pi}{n}}S\end{equation}

**Case n=3:**

- [Hadwiger–Finsler inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Finsler_inequality), $k=1 \approx 1.00550827956352=tan{\frac{\pi}{3}}-tan{\frac{\pi}{5}}$:

\begin{equation}a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \geq 4 \sqrt{3}S+ (a - b)^{2} + (b - c)^{2} + (c - a)^{2}\end{equation}

**Case n=4:** [our paper](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/81-86.pdf), $k=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $k=tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}-tan{\frac{\pi}{6}}$

\begin{equation} a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \ge 4S + \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum{(a-b)^2}\end{equation}

**See also:**

- [Weitzenböck's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck%27s_inequality)
- [Hadwiger–Finsler inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Finsler_inequality)
- [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjectured inequality, with $k=\tan{\frac{\pi}{n}}-\tan{\frac{\pi}{n+2}}$, is false for $n=3$. More specifically, the constant factor $k=1$ is optimal in the Hadwiger--Finsler inequality: e.g., consider $a=b=1$ and $c\approx0$.

Comment: I will chesk by my computer now. Thank You very much.

Comment: I check in long time, but I can not find the optimal formular of $k$

Comment: So far, we don't even seem to have a good expression for the optimal $k$ covering the cases of $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Comment: I think optimal of $k \approx \tan\frac{\pi}{n}- \tan\frac{\pi}{n+2}$

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you are looking for is "quantitative isoperimetric inequalities". The case of polygons was solved in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4460

The "quantitative" term in the paper above is not necessarily of the form you seek. It involves the standard deviation of the radii and central angles.