# In arbitrary cyclic polygon then $\sum_{i<j} x_{ij}^\alpha \ge \sum_{i<j} y_{ij}^\alpha $

Tags: inequalities, plane-geometry, polygons

> > I am looking for a proof of the inequality as follows:
> >
> > **Conjecture:** Let $A_1A_2....A_n$ be the regular polygon incribed a circle $(O)$. Let $B_1B_2....B_n$ be a polygon incribed the circle $(O)$. Denote $x_{ij}=A_iA_j$ and $y_{ij}=B_{i}B_{j}$ then:
> >
> > $$\sum_{i<j} x_{ij}^\alpha \ge \sum_{i<j} y_{ij}^\alpha $$

Where $ 1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$.

- The case $ \alpha = 1 $ was proved in our paper in [here](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.pdf)
- The case $ \alpha = 2 $ was proved in [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304456/an-inequality-of-a-cyclic-polygon)

**Example:**

- $n=3$, let $ABC$ be a triangle with sidelength $a, b, c$ then we have the inequality as follows:

$$a^\alpha + b^\alpha+ c^\alpha \leq 3\times 3^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}R^\alpha$$
Where $ 1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$, $R$ is circumradius.

**See also:**

Comment: Dear Mr Dao, I think polygon $B_1B_2...B_n$ need be convex?

Comment: @TranQuangHung I don't think that

Comment: That's right Mr Dao, thank you very much. I thought the regular polygon was convex but this is not really.