# An inequality related to area and sidelengths of a polygon $Area(A_1A_2....A_n) \le \frac{1}{n}cotg{\frac{\pi}{n}} \sum_{i=1}^nA_iA_{i+1}^2$

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, polygons

$\DeclareMathOperator\Area{Area}\DeclareMathOperator\cotg{cotg}$I am looking for a proof (or a reference) of an inequality related to area and the sidelengths of a polygon as follows:

> Let $A_1A_2\cdots A_n$ be an arbitrary polygon, then:
>
> $$\Area(A_1A_2\cdots A_n) \le \frac{1}{4}\cotg{\frac{\pi}{n}} \sum_{i=1}^nA_iA_{i+1}^2$$

- This is a generalization of [Weitzenböck's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck%27s_inequality).
- You can see a stronger version at [Strengthened version of Isoperimetric inequality with n-polygon](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299056/strengthened-version-of-isoperimetric-inequality-with-n-polygon).

**Geometric meanings:** $$\Area(A_1A_2\cdots A_n) \le \frac{\Area(1)+\Area(2)+\dotsb +\Area(n)}{n}.$$

[image: Figure illustrating geometric meaning of the inequality]

PS: I found this inequality long time ago, that time I thought this is old inequality. But today, I think this is new because I can not see any reference for the inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the indices $i$ in $A_i$ are taken mod $n$,
so "$A_{n+1}$" is to be identified with $A_1$.
This must be a known isoperimetric inequality,
but it's easier to prove than to find in the literature.

Fix the area $\cal A$ of the $n$-gon.  By a standard compactness argument 
there exists an $n$-gon $A_1 A_2 \ldots A_n$ that minimizes
$\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i A_{i+1})^2$.
We first show that this polygon is convex (but possibly with
$A_{i-1} A_i A_{i+1}$ collinear for some $i$).
Indeed if it is not we can replace it by the convex hull,
with each side $A_j A_k$ of the convex hull
divided into $k-j$ equal subsegments; this both increases the area
and decreases $\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i A_{i+1})^2$,
so we can shrink the polygon back to area $\cal A$
and make the sum of its sides' squares even smaller.

Given convexity, fix all but one of the vertices, say $A_2$.
Then $A_2$ is limited to a line parallel to $A_1 A_3$,
and we readily see (as by choosing coordinates that make $A_1,A_3 = (\pm 1, 0)$ )
that $(A_1 A_2)^2 + (A_2 A_3)^2$ is minimized when
$(A_1 A_2) = (A_2 A_3)$.  Thus the minimizing $n$-gon
has all sides equal, say with each $(A_i A_{i+1}) = s$;
and then $ns^2$ is minimized when $ns$ is $-$ but $ns$ is the perimeter,
and the usual isoperimetric inequality for $n$-gons
then finishes the proof that the area-$\cal A$ polygon 
with the smallest $\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i A_{i+1})^2$ is regular.

Answer (score 10):

Cauchy–Schwarz tells you that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert A_iA_{i+1}\rvert^2\geq \frac{P^2}{n}$$
where $P$ is the perimeter of the polygon. Then we need the inequality $$P^2\geq 4n\tan(\pi/n)A$$ which is the classical isoperimetric inequality for polygons with many proofs in the literature, analytic, geometric and algebraic. See [Fan, Taussky, and Todd - An algebraic proof of the isoperimetric inequality for polygons](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24534441) article and its references, for example.

Comment: Could You help? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299056/strengthened-version-of-isoperimetric-inequality-with-n-polygon